# C# automapper check all enum values are in map

Tags: c#, automapper

I am mapping from my domain model to a databaseDto. Both hold an enum representing a range of states.

Is there any way of checking all the values in one enum can be mapped with automapper once the mapper has been built from its configuration (or maybe in a unit-test)

Comment: Did you try to look at custom resolvers in automapper?

Comment: What have you tried to solve this? Did you look at how to enumerate over an enum's values? Is this not just a simple `foreach(possibleEnumValue) CheckThatItDoesntBlowUp();` solution?

Comment: there is an in built assertion of the configuration with `Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid()` afaik, but how could you possibly check this without having all possible input values which naturally will be unknown during service startup.

Comment: Edited the question to make it clearer. It is after the mapper is built from its configuration I want to check all enum values could be mapped.

Answer (score 0):

You can use example code below;

```
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateMaps();

            Lender src = new Lender()
            {
                Id = 1,
                Name = "Bob",
                ClaimTypes = ClaimType.A | ClaimType.C
            };

            LenderServiceModel dest = Mapper.Map<LenderServiceModel>(src);

            Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1}", dest.Id, dest.Name);

            foreach(var claimType in dest.ClaimTypes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(claimType);
            }
        }

        private static void CreateMaps()
        {
            Mapper.CreateMap<Lender, LenderServiceModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.ClaimTypes, opts => opts.MapFrom(src =>
                    src.ClaimTypes.ToString().Split(new string[]{", "}, StringSplitOptions.None).ToList()));
        }
    }

    [Flags]
    public enum ClaimType : int
    {
        A = 1,
        B = 2,
        C = 4
    }

    public class Lender
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public ClaimType ClaimTypes { get; set; }
    }

    public class LenderServiceModel 
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }

        public string Name { get; set; }

        public List<string> ClaimTypes { get; set; }
    }
```